# cameratag setup from jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, webcam

I have a cameratag APP and I want to permit several users to upload their videos. I should setup my camera recorder with this tag:

```
<camera id='[CAMERA_ID]' data-app-id='[YOUR_APP_UUID]'></camera>
```

how can I change the id and data-app-id attibutes from jquery? I tried:

```
$('camera').attr('data-app-id', 'newval');
```

but it doesn't work, any idea or link to examples?

thanks

Comment: $("#CAMERA_ID").attr("data-app-id","newval");

Comment: yeah I also tried $("#myForm").find("camera").attr("data-app-id","newval"); with no success

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to set the id without Javascript : write it directly in your HTML file.

If you really need to do this in JS, here's the solution :

```
$('YOUR CAMERA SELECTOR').attr('id', '[CAMERA_ID]').attr('data-app-id', '[YOUR_APP_UUID]');
// this line cause a rescan of the DOM for any uninitialized <camera> tags.
CameraTag.setup();
```

If your camera tag was already initialized, you need to destroy and recreate it, cameratag can't change the id on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

Your JQuery selector won't work because the `<camera>` tag translates to normal HTML. For example the following code will produce the following HTML:

```
<camera id='myCamId' data-app-id='123456'></camera>
```

---

```
<div id="myCamId" class="camera_tag" style="width: 300px; height: 200px;">
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" id="myCamId_swf" name="myCamId_swf"
        data="//cameratag.com/2.1/camera.swf?1862032" width="100%" height="100%">
    <param name="allowfullscreen" value="true">
    <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always">
    <param name="wmode" value="transparent">
    <param name="flashvars"
           value="videoServer=undefined&amp;videoUUID=undefined&amp;cameraUUID=undefined&amp;domID=myCamId&amp;maxLength=30&amp;hResolution=300&amp;vResolution=200&amp;fps=24&amp;videoBitRate=undefined&amp;skipAutoDetect=false&amp;flipRecordPreview=true">
</object>
<div id="myCamId_start_screen" style="font-size: 14px; position: absolute; display: none;"
     class="cameratag_screen cameratag_start"><a class="cameratag_select_prompt">choose a method below to submit
    your video</a><a class="cameratag_primary_link cameratag_record_link cameratag_record"><span
        class="cameratag_action_icon"></span><br><span class="cameratag_prompt_label">record from webcam</span></a><a
        id="myCamId_upload_link" class="cameratag_primary_link cameratag_upload_link cameratag_upload"
        style="position: relative; z-index: 1;"><span class="cameratag_action_icon"></span><br><span
        class="cameratag_prompt_label">upload a file</span></a><a class="cameratag_primary_link cameratag_sms_link"><span
        class="cameratag_action_icon"></span><br><span
        class="cameratag_prompt_label">record from phone</span></a><img class="cameratag_settings_btn"
                                                                        src="//cameratag.com/assets/gear.png">

    <div id="html5_18o7pgr4s1lt418amvom1ddi18a23_container" class="moxie-shim moxie-shim-html5"
         style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 0px; height: 0px; overflow: hidden; z-index: 0;">
        <input id="html5_18o7pgr4s1lt418amvom1ddi18a23" type="file"
               accept="video/mp4,video/x-m4v,video/*,video/webm"
               style="font-size: 999px; opacity: 0; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%;">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="cameratag_screen cameratag_error" style="display: block;">
    <div class="cameratag_error_message">invalid camera uuid</div>
    <img class="cameratag_settings_btn" src="//cameratag.com/assets/gear.png"></div>
<div class="cameratag_screen cameratag_detect" style="display: none;">
    <div class="cameratag_prompt">wave to the camera</div>
</div>
<div class="cameratag_screen cameratag_count" style="display: none;">
    <div class="cameratag_countdown_status"></div>
    <div class="cameratag_prompt">recording in</div>
</div>
<div class="cameratag_screen cameratag_upload" style="display: none;">
    <div class="cameratag_upload_status"></div>
    <div class="cameratag_prompt">uploading...</div>
</div>
<div class="cameratag_screen cameratag_recording cameratag_stop_recording" style="display: none;">
    <div class="cameratag_prompt">click to stop recording <span class="cameratag_record_timer_prompt">(30)</span>
    </div>
    <img src="//cameratag.com/assets/recording.gif"></div>
<div class="cameratag_screen cameratag_playback cameratag_stop_playback" style="display: none;">
    <div class="cameratag_prompt">click to skip review</div>
</div>
<div class="cameratag_screen cameratag_accept" style="display: none;"><a
        class="cameratag_accept_btn cameratag_publish"><span class="button_label">✓ Accept</span></a><a
        class="cameratag_rerecord_btn cameratag_record"><span class="button_label">♻ Re-record</span></a><a
        class="cameratag_play_btn cameratag_play"><span class="button_label">↵ Review Recording</span></a></div>
<div class="cameratag_screen cameratag_wait" style="display: none;">
    <div class="cameratag_spinner"><img src="//cameratag.com/assets/loading.gif"><br><span
            class="cameratag_wait_message">please wait while we push pixels</span></div>
</div>
<div class="cameratag_screen cameratag_completed" style="display: none;">
    <div class="cameratag_thumb_bg"></div>
    <div class="cameratag_checkmark"><span class="check">✔</span> published</div>
</div>
<div class="cameratag_screen cameratag_sms" style="display: none;">
    <div class="cameratag_sms_prompt">Enter your <b>mobile phone number</b> below and we will text you a link for
        mobile recording<br><input class="cameratag_sms_input" type="text"><br><a href="javascript:"
                                                                                  class="cameratag_send_sms">Send
            Mobile Link</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="javascript:" class="cameratag_goto_start">cancel</a></div>
</div>
<div class="cameratag_screen cameratag_check_phone" style="display: none;">
    <div class="cameratag_check_phone_prompt">Check your phone for mobile recording instructions</div>
    <div class="cameratag_check_phone_url">or vsist http://cameratag.com/m/undefined your mobile browser</div>
</div>
<input id="myCamId_video_uuid" type="hidden" name="myCamId[video_uuid]" value=""></div>
```

I would look at the [JS Methods](https://cameratag.com/docs/camera_methods) for the right solution

Comment: thanks for your help Shlomi. unfortunately cameratag.com docs isn't clear enough to me. maybe have you got some link with some example? thanks.